# Efficient detection if value at memory address has been changed?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded

This more a general question. Consider an external device. From time to time this device writes data via its device driver to a specific memory address. I want to write a small C program which read out this data. Is there a better way than just polling this address to check if the value has been changed? I want to keep the CPU load low.

**I have done some further research**

Is "memory mapped IO" an option? My naive idea is to let the external device writes a flag to a "memory mapped IO"-address which triggers a kernel device driver. The driver then "informs" the program which proceed the value. Can this work? How can a driver informs the program?

Comment: Generally you'd do this by having a "notify" channel of some sort, which you could either do a blocking read() on, or include in a larger select()

Comment: This is what IRQs are for...

Comment: Thx for your answers. What is if the external device can't trigger an interrupt? Is memory mapped IO an option?

Comment: What causes the device driver to run?  If this is a hypothetical question, then you are introducing some unrealistic constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The answer may depend on what processor you intend to use, what the device is and possibly whether you are using an operating system or RTOS.

Memory mapped I/O *per se* is not a solution, that simply refers to I/O device registers that can be directly addressed via normal memory access instructions.  Most devices will generate an interrupt when certain registers are updated or contain new valid data.

In general if using an RTOS you can arrange for the device driver to signal via a suitable IPC mechanism any client thread(s) that need to handle the data.  If you are not using an RTOS, you could simply register a callback with the device driver which it would call whenever the data is updated.  What the client does in the call back is its business - including reading the new data.

If the device in question generates interrupts, then the handling can be done on interrupt, if  the device is capable of DMA, then it can handle blocks of data autonomously before teh DMA controller generates an DMA interrupt to a handler.